# Oracle SQL: NVARCHAR2 contains a number field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has an Id field that is a number. I would like to check to see if that number is in a table that is surrounded by $$^$$ ex: `$$^$$1265$$^$$` is supposed to match the id field `1265` in the next table. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM VarTable a, IDTable b 
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR2(400 CHAR), b.id) LIKE a.var_value;`
```

I have also tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM VarTable  a, IDTable b 
WHERE a.var_value LIKE CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), b.id);
```

The bottom throws a "missing expression error" and the top one throws a "missing right parenthesis" error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using SQL Server `convert()`.  The function does something else in Oracle (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620)).

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM VarTable a join
     IDTable b
     on a.var_value LIKE '%$$'||cast(b.id as varchar2(255))||'$$%';
```

You can also use `to_char()` to convert a number to a specific string representation.

Comment: This worked perfect. I tried using to_char() earlier, but would always get an error. Is the `||` concatenation in oracle? I was attempting to use `+`...

Comment: Gordon - just curious: in situations like this I usually let Oracle implicitly cast for me: `... LIKE '%$$' || b.id || '$$%'`. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: @EdGibbs . . . It is a fine idea for `||` because the cast is obvious.  In other cases, such as arguments to functions, I put in explicit casts for maintainability.  Because I use SQL Server a lot, I put in explicit casts all the time for string concatenation.  SQL Server uses `+` for string concatenation and without the explicit cast it generates an error.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff! I also have some habits that come from working with multiple databases, and I'll add this one to the arsenal. As always, I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is a number and a varchar, I would go for:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM VarTable a, 
       IDTable b 
 WHERE a.var_value LIKE '%$$'||b.id||'&&%';
```

Comment: What if a.var_value=$$^$$912659&&^&& and b.id=1265? Yes it will fail.